# jquery plugin for gallery and image slide show with thumbnails

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, image-gallery

I am searching for a jquery plugin for gallery and image slideshow with thumbnails in my application. (exactly same like http://www.airbnb.com/rooms/28668). These images are dynamically uploaded in my application. I tried to integrate cycle plugin but it seems there is no option for scrolling thumbnails to left and right as shown in ref site. Since I am new to jquery and javascript I am not in a position to extend the cycle functionality and write the code to achieve it right now. So any inputs is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

JCarousel is a fairly solid jquery plugin for controlling a list of images. Might be something to look into, its quite flexible, though has its flaws ^^ you can quite easily combine it with  the knockout library or probably some simple jQuery to dynamically load large versions of the slide thumbnails.

[JCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)
[Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) (if you feel like being fancy and using knockout too =D )

Alternatively you could use JCarousel alongside another plugin such as http://galleria.aino.se/ to achieve your desired functionality. I used jQuerys galleria plugin a few years back and found they complimented each other quite nicely. This blog has a tutorial on how to merge them, looks fairly brief, I don't remember what I did for mine 2 years ago =D http://www.leonkessler.com/blog/?p=9 . I am afraid I have not been very helpful, if you do find a plugin that suits your needs would you let me know? ^^

Good luck :)

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I need to scroll thumbnail image as well as main image also.. Like the one in http://www.airbnb.com/rooms/28668

Comment: Hmm yes I see your point, why I mentioned the use of knockout to change the main image. But you did say you weren't in the position to extend the code, so I guess my bad. I don't know of any plugins that do exactly what you want on their own. I have worked on several projects similar to what you seem to be working on and have had to add a lot of random code to get things to work for my specific needs. Think you'll find that everywhere :P I will update my answer with another possible solution I used a while back, was fairly simple and didn't require extensive extra code.